# Add File Paths to Add-in/Macros Security Programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to add new paths to the Add-in/Macros Security programmatically

i know they should exist in

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0????\AutomationOptions\LookInFolders

but i checked my registery and that doesnt exist

im using Windows 7 64bit.
Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.
C#

any idea how to add paths ? ?  i cant find AutomationOptions\LookInFolders any where and i dont know if i should add it and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
    key =
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(
            @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\AutomationOptions");
    if (key != null)
    {
        key = key.CreateSubKey(@"LookInFolders");
        key.SetValue(Name,Path);
        key.Close();
```

i got it solved

Comment: and delete file paths like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686660/delete-key-in-lookinfolders-vs-2008-9-0-using-msbuild ?