# Delete Key in LookInFolders VS 2008 - 9.0 using MsBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, registry, visual-studio-addins

I use MsBuild to Registry a VS Addin.

I need implement target Uninstall in MSBuild.

How can I delete my addin path in SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AutomationOptions\LookInFolders registry using MsBuild ?

For install, I use

```
    <Target Name="RegistryExtensions">

            <Message Text="Registry AddIn..."></Message>
            <Registry.Set
                RegistryHive="LocalMachine"
                Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AutomationOptions\LookInFolders"
                Value="$(ProgramFiles)\LifeCycle\AddIns"
                DataType="String" />

            <Message Text="Adding LifeCycle.targets to VisualStudio SafeImports ..."></Message>
            <Registry.Set
                RegistryHive="LocalMachine"
                Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\MSBuild\SafeImports"
                Value="MyLifeCycle"
                DataType="String"
                Data="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\LifeCycle.targets" ContinueOnError="true">
            </Registry.Set>
        </Target>

    <Target Name="UnRegistryAddin">
<!-- TODO -->
        </Target>
```

I try get the value, but I get Empty string

```
    <Registry.GetKey
        RegistryHive="LocalMachine"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AutomationOptions\LookInFolders"
        Value="$(ProgramFiles)\LifeCycle\AddIns">
        <Output TaskParameter="Data" PropertyName="Addin1"/>
    </Registry.GetKey>

    <Message Text=" Addin1 $(Addin1)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sue `DeleteKey`/`DeleteKeyTree` Registry tasks, see [MSBuild Extension Pack help](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.6.0/html/9c8ecf24-3d8d-2b2d-e986-3e026dda95fe.htm)

```
<!-- Delete a key -->
        <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.Registry 
           TaskAction="DeleteKey" 
           RegistryHive="LocalMachine" 
           Key="SOFTWARE\ANewTemp"/>
```

I believe it should work with the syntax you are used for the `Set` task:

```
<Registry.DeleteKey ...
```

Important (required attributes to be set):

- DeleteKey (Required: RegistryHive, Key)
- DeleteKeyTree (Required: RegistryHive, Key)

Comment: I try get the value first for detect if it exists but I get empty string.